# Fatal Python error: _Py_HashRandomization_Init: failed to get random numbers to initialize Python Python runtime state: preinitialized

Tags: python, php, laravel, symfony, process

I am trying to run a python script from laravel using process but it is not working.

**My code:**

```php
$process = new Process(['C:/Users/hrish/AppData/Local/Programs/Python/Python39/python.exe', 'C:\xampp\htdocs\N\MovieRSystem\app\Models\top_movies.py']);
        
        $process->run();
        if (!$process->isSuccessful()) {
            throw new ProcessFailedException($process);
        }
```

**Error:**

```
Symfony\Component\Process\Exception\ProcessFailedException
The command ""C:/Users/hrish/AppData/Local/Programs/Python/Python39/python.exe" C:\xampp\htdocs\N\MovieRSystem\public\top_movies.py" failed. Exit Code: 1(General error) Working directory: C:\xampp\htdocs\N\MovieRSystem\public Output: ================ Error Output: ================ Fatal Python error: _Py_HashRandomization_Init: failed to get random numbers to initialize Python Python runtime state: preinitialized
```

Comment: Can you show how it looks when you run the python script manually? Does it show the same error?

Answer (score 0):

You can try using **shell_exec()** command instead to run your python program like this

```
 <?php
    $command = escapeshellcmd('python C:\xampp\htdocs\N\MovieRSystem\app\Models\top_movies.py');
    $output = shell_exec($command);
    echo $output;
 ?>
```

Comment: I was having the same issue as OP but so far nobody seemed to has found a fix, your solution is the only one that got me further, thanks :)